# execute on jQuery load if not already available

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some templating reason, I append to be in the following html situation:

```
<body>
  <p>Content</p>
  <script>
    // Some jQuery content
  </script>
  <p>More content</p>

  <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm trying to write some code so that the jQuery content gets executed *after* jQuery loaded if not already loaded.

```
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
  // The jQuery content
} else {
  // WHAT?
  document.onready = function() {
    // The jQuery content
  }
}
```

I hope I'm clear!

Comment: window.onload ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would apply a helper function at the top of your page:

```
var asyncjquery=[];
$=asyncjquery.push.bind(asyncjquery);
```

So you can call the jquery function as normal ( $.ajax, $()() wont work):

```
$(function(){
  alert("hi");
});
```

then after the jQuery load you can do this:

```
asyncjquery.forEach(func=>$(func));
```